# How to add button in rte editor toolbar TYPO3

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, ckeditor4.x

I want to add button in rte editor toolbar. On clicking it automatically a specific image should be inserted in editor.
Here is an example image link https://ucarecdn.com/06a0c19f-1f75-4531-9210-e18409ee72b0/Capture.PNG

Comment: You can use [Toolbar Configurator](https://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/toolbarconfigurator/index.html#advanced) tool from the official site for creating YAML configuration. This is what you want I guess.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me but i am creating an extension and i need this functionality. i don't know where to add this and how to do this.

Comment: For what do you need a button? To style your links (with an `<a>` tag)? To create a form (with a `<button>` tag?

Comment: i need button to automatically add an image with download link to some file basically it is an download icon

Answer (score 0):

You will need to override the YAML configuration for this,

1) PageTsConfig: Typoscript settings

```
RTE.tt_content.types.textmedia.bodytext.preset = full 
RTE.config.tx_news_domain_model_news.bodytext.preset = default
```

2) ext_localconf.php

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['RTE']['Presets']['my_preset'] = 'EXT:my_layout_extension/Configuration/RTE/Default.yaml';
```

Only you need to move Default.yaml to the 'EXT:my_layout_extension/Configuration/RTE' directoty. For more [NITSAN Blog](https://www.nitsan.in/blog/post/simple-steps-to-configure-ckeditor-typo3/) and [typo3worx](https://typo3worx.eu/2017/02/configure-ckeditor-in-typo3/) blog will help you.

Hope this makes sense!